# Help provide a proof of the Helly–Bray theorem

Tags: probability

Given a probability space $(\Omega,\cal F, \Bbb P)$, the distribution function of a random variable $X$ is defined as $F(x)=\Bbb P\{X \le x\}$. Now if $F_1,F_2,...,F_{\infty}$ are distribution functions, then the question is

> Is $F_n \xrightarrow{w} F_{\infty}$ equivalent to $\lim_{n\uparrow\infty}\int\phi dF_n=\int\phi dF_{\infty}$ for every $\phi \in C(\Bbb R)$?

Here ${F_n}\xrightarrow{w}{F_\infty }$ means weak convergence, and the integral involved are Riemann-Stieltjes integrals.

Someone has pointed out that this is the [Helly-Bray theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helly%E2%80%93Bray_theorem), which says the above claim is true when $\phi$ is bounded. I have searched the Internet but was not able to find a proof of the theorem. Can anyone help provide a proof? Thanks!

Comment: [Helly-Bray Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helly%E2%80%93Bray_theorem)

Comment: Please specify more precisely what you mean. Are all $F_i$ meant to be CDFs of probability measures? Does $F_n \to F_\infty$ mean pointwise convergence or convergence in distribution? If it's the latter, what is your definition of convergence in distribution? In any case, you should restrict $\phi$ so some subfamily, so that all occuring integrals are well-defined. If the $F_i$ are distribution functions of probability measures, then it is enough to consider bounded functions. If the corresponding measures are only locally finite, you need compactly supported functions.

Comment: @Dominik Hi. Thank you for your suggestion. I have made the refinement.

Comment: I'm unclear what you're asking here.  Are you asking for a proof of the Helly-Bray theorem, or an answer to your boxed question about the equivalence of the conditions?  The answer to your boxed question is no, they are not equivalent.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thank you for your comment. This question comes from my teacher's lecture note. I am not sure but I myself is confused by the question. Can I ask a question first. If in the boxed question the "convergence in distribution" is replaced by "weak convergence", is the claim true?

Comment: Does "weak convergence" here have the usual meaning of "for every $\phi \in C_b(\mathbb{R}), \int \phi \,dF_n \to \int \phi \,dF$"?  This is not equivalent to "for every $\phi \in C(\mathbb{R}), \int \phi\,dF_n \to \int\phi\,dF$".  Is that what you want to know?  You should already be suspicious because for a general continuous $\phi$ and a general distribution function $F$, the integral $\int \phi\,dF$ need not even exist.

Comment: A detailed proof of this theorem is available via this YouTube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yXMzr3h5eYE&list=PLo4jXE-LdDTS5BYqea-LcHdtjKwVcepP7&index=10&t=1321s

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I will try to give an extensive answer to this problem. Instead of working with distribution functions, I will work with the corresponding random variables $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_\infty$ to make notation easier.

**Is the claim correct if we allow $\phi$ to be any continuous function?**
Unfortunately, the answer is no. The first problem is, that in general $E[f(x_i)]$ doesn't need to exist for every continuous funciton $f$. Take for example the [Cauchy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution). This distribution doesn't have finite expectation, so we can construct a counterexample by assuming $X$ to be Cauchy distributed and setting $X_n = \frac{X}{n}$. Then clearly $X_n$ converges almost surely to $X_\infty = 0$, and therefore also weakly. But for $f(x) = x$ the value of $E[f(X_n)]$ is undefined, except for $E[f(X_\infty)] = E[0] = 0$.

**What if we restrict $\phi$ to the class of functions so that all $E[f(X_n)]$ exist?**
Unfortunately, this still won't work. Assume $P(X_n = \frac{1}{n}) = 1 - \frac{1}{n}$ and $P(X_n = n + \frac{1}{n} - 1) = \frac{1}{n}$. It's easy to see that $X_n$ converges in probability to $X_\infty = 0$, and therefore weakly. Choosing $f$ to be the identity, we can see that $E[f(x_n)] = 1$ doesn't converge to $E[f(x_\infty)] = 0$.

The problem in this case is, that a general continuous function can "blow up" a neglibible part of the distribution.

**What if we restrict $\phi$ to be a continuous, bounded function?**
In this case, the equivalence is correct.

To see that the convergence of the functions implies weak convergence, let $x$ be a continuity point of the distribution of $X_\infty$. Now we can approximate the Indicator $f(t) = I\{t \le x\}$ from below and from the top by continuous functions. Namely we choose $\underline{f_m}$ to be one on $(-\infty, x - \frac{1}{m}]$, zero on $[x, \infty)$ and linear inbetween. Similarly, we choose $\overline{f_m}$ to be one on $(-\infty, x]$, one on $[x+ \frac{1}{m}, \infty)$ and linear inbetween. I recommend doing a quick sketch of these functions.

We can now easily see that $\underline{f_m} \le f \le \overline{f_m}$ and therefore 
$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} E[\underline{f_m}(X_n)] \le \lim \limits_{n \to \infty}E[f(X_n)] \le \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} E[\overline{f_m}(X_n)]$$
which by assumption implies
$$E[\underline{f_m}(X_\infty)] \le \lim \limits_{n \to \infty}P(X_n \le x) \le E[\overline{f_m}(X_\infty)].$$

Now observe that $P(X_\infty \le x - \frac{1}{m}) \le E[\underline{f_m}(X_\infty)]$ and a similar inequality for the upper bound yields
$$P\left(X_\infty \le x - \frac{1}{m}\right) \le \lim \limits_{n \to \infty}P(X_n \le x) \le P\left(X_\infty \le x + \frac{1}{m}\right).$$
The assertion now follows from observing that $x$ is a continuity point of $F_\infty$ and letting $m \to \infty$.

**The other direction of the equivalence** is a bit more tedious work. This proof works by simple approximations, I will only sketch how it works.

First we note that weakly convergent measures are [tight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tightness_of_measures), so the first step of the approximation is to restrict our continuous function to some compact interval $K$. Since $F_\infty$ is monotone, it has at most countably many points of discontinuity. Therefore we can choose a sequence of [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_an_interval) $S_m$ of $K$ that consist only of continuity points of $F_\infty$ and whose mesh converges to zero. If $S_m = \{x_1, \ldots, x_m\}$, we choose to approximate our continuous, bounded function $f$ by $f_m(t) = \sum \limits_{i = 1}^{m - 1} f(x_i) I\{x_i < t \le x_{i + 1}\}$. Observe that $E[I\{x_i < X_\infty \le x_{i + 1}\}] = P_\infty(x_{i + 1}) - P_\infty(x_i)$.

Now the rest of this proof consists in showing that our approximation is actually good enough to ensure $E[f(X_n)] \to E[f(X_\infty)]$ actually holds.

**Can we expand or further restrict our class of functions, so that the equivalence still holds?**
The answer is yes. A list of possible characterizations of weak convergence can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures#Weak_convergence_of_measures).

**Can we restrict our functions to continuous functions that are compactly supported?**
The answer is no, take for example $X_n \sim \mathcal{U}[n, n + 1]$. Then $X_n$ doesn't converge weakly [as it isn't tight], but for every compactly supported function $f$ we have $E[f(X_n)] \to 0$.

However, the notion of convergence that is induced by only considering compactly supported functions is called [vague convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vague_topology). It can be shown [Thm 5.20 in *Kallenberg*] that a sequence of random variables converges weakly iff it converges vaguely and is tight.

Answer (score 0):

I can refer you this link (http://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/gordanz/notes/weak.pdf). Look for the portmanteau theorem here.